# AngularJS ui-router state not detected after server side redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

When there is a serverside redirect (301 permanent) ui-router does not detect the initial state. Html5mode is enabled.

ASP.NET MVC 5 is used for the backend and the first page load is serverside rendered and then ui-router takes over after that.

Example:

```
angular.controller('MainAppController', function ($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e) {
        console.log('state change detected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the source of ui-router the problem was a trailing slash in the state url.

When there was a serverside redirect (301) the trailing slash was not recognized and state was not found. Removing the trailing slash fixed the problem.